# Iterating over dictionary with given value in key till it reaches to custom endpoint

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, graph

I have a dictionary with structure `{key:[(next_key, value),...],....}` as follow:

```
d = {0: [(1, 10), (5, 9)], 1: [(0, 14), (3, 3), (4, 17)]}
```

endpoints are:

`end_points = [2,3,4,5]`

Here I need to iterate values in `d` with `next_key` found in `key` and next to next key and so on until the next key value is in endpoint. So when I reach to endpoint I need a dictionary contains end_points as key element and multiplication of all values iterated over it. i.e. for `end_point 3` values will be `10*3 = 30` and for `end_point 4` value will be 10*17
but the problem comes here because 0's element points to key value 1 and it's element points to 0 hence I need a way to brake that loop and consider it's value in multiplication to reach to end_points.

Basically I observed automata which may or may not contains loop over path and I need multiplication of values to reach to end_points which can be treated as final state.

So far I have tried:

```
d = {0: [(1, 10), (5, 9)], 1: [(0, 14), (3, 3), (4, 17)]} # dictionary
end_points = [2,3,4,5] # end points

end_points_cost = {}
loop = lambda x : 1 / (1-x)

for key in d:
    temp = 1  # multiplication constant
    flag=True
    for next_key, value in d[key]:
        if next_key in end_points_cost:
            temp = end_points[next_key]
        if next_key not in end_points:
            temp = temp * value
        elif next_key in end_points:
            temp = temp * value
            end_points_cost[next_key] = temp
        elif key in [i[0] for i in d[next_key]]:
            temp = temp * loop(d[key][1] * value)
            end_points_cost[next_key] = temp
```

my Output:

```
{3: 42, 4: 714, 5: 90}
```

Desired output:

```
{3: Fraction(-3,139), 4: Fraction(-17,139), 5: Fraction(-9,139)}
```

---

## Update:

```
d = {0: {1: Fraction(7, 12), 3: Fraction(5, 12)}, 1: {0: Fraction(2, 5), 2: Fraction(3, 5)}, 2: {1: Fraction(1, 1)}}

end_points = [3]
```

with help of [find_all_paths](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/) method  I am able to calculate path `[0, 3]` towards my key, but problem is I am able to calculate loop value of key 0 to value 1 and vice-versa but key 1 also has another loop with key 2 and I am facing problem on  how to include sub loops.

I have tried :

```
loop_list = [v for v,k in d.items() if source in k and v in d[source]] # considering 0 as source
```

but this is not calculating sub result of 1 which is key 1 to key 2 which needs to be considered.

Comment: expecting solution with built-in modules only

Comment: really hard to understand what you want,please give a more complete example.

Comment: I don't understand your examples: Why do you expect negative values in your first example? And which value is expected for `2` in this case? And which value do you expect in the the second example? I would say `1.0` for `3`, because finally your automata will arrive in `3` (it might take a lot of transitions/steps!), but then I don't really understand your problem so might be completely wrong...

Answer (score 3):

You are describing a directed graph. [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/) can help you for all your graph theory needs!

```
import networkx as nx
from fractions import Fraction
d = {0: [(1, 10), (5, 9)], 1: [(0, 14), (3, 3), (4, 17)]}

G = nx.DiGraph()

for n1,n2s in d.items():
  for n2,weight in n2s:
    G.add_edge(n1, n2, weight=weight)

start_point = 0
for end_point in [2, 3, 4, 5]:
  if end_point in G:
    path = nx.shortest_path(G,start_point, end_point)
    print("Path : %s " % path)
    product = 1
    for n1, n2 in zip(path, path[1:]):
      product *= G.get_edge_data(n1,n2)['weight'] 
    print("Product : %d " % product)
    print()
```

It outputs :

```
Path : [0, 1, 3] 
Product : 30 

Path : [0, 1, 4] 
Product : 170 

Path : [0, 5] 
Product : 9
```

As for your second example, you just need to modify the graph initialization:

```
d = {0: {1: Fraction(7, 12), 3: Fraction(5, 12)}, 1: {0: Fraction(2, 5), 2: Fraction(3, 5)}, 2: {1: Fraction(1, 1)}}

G = nx.DiGraph()

for n1,n2s in d.items():
  for n2,weight in n2s.items():
    G.add_edge(n1, n2, weight=weight)

start_point = 0
for end_point in [2, 3, 4, 5]:
  if end_point in G:
    path = nx.shortest_path(G,start_point, end_point)
    print("Path : %s " % path)
    product = 1
    for n1, n2 in zip(path, path[1:]):
      product *= G.get_edge_data(n1,n2)['weight']
    print("Product : %r " % product)
    print()
```

It outputs:

```
Path : [0, 1, 2] 
Product : Fraction(7, 20) 

Path : [0, 3] 
Product : Fraction(5, 12)
```

Now, whatever library you use, multiplying positive fractions will always result in positive fractions.

Comment: I have already achieved this flow but my problem is I have to have consider that loop where 0 points to 1 and 1 points to 0 so at the end when 1 points to 0... so I need to consider path 0,1,2 - all multiplication you provided but also consider the loop made between node 0 and 1. In your case you considered: x to y to z but y also points to x which points back to y to z so I need to consider such possible loops while exploring graph.

Answer (score 1):

(You didn't say, but your examples suggest that `0` is the starting point for every path.)

If you're expecting a single answer for each endpoint, you have to decide what path to use when there's more than one choice.  The usual case is the [shortest path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem), which applies if you can identify a suitable definition of "shortest" (perhaps the number of steps or the product should be minimized).

In the case where the shortest path is measured in steps (which may still leave more than one possible product!), this is solved via [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).  There is an implementation there which should be trivial to adapt; note that the simplest queue in the Python standard library is `collections.deque`.  When enqueuing each node, store with it the product up to that point (which is [1 for the initial node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product)), so that when an endpoint is reached you know its product.  Keep working until you have encountered all the endpoints.

In the case where the product is to be minimized, you want [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), modified to have the initial distance be 1 (again) and to multiply weights rather than adding them.  The Python standard library provides the requisite priority queue via the `heapq` module.

Answer (score 0):

```
from fractions import Fraction

loop_probability = lambda x : Fraction(1, 1-x)

def find_all_paths(next_stage_probability, start, end, path=[]):
    path = path + [start]
    if start == end:
        return [path]
    if not next_stage_probability.__contains__(start):
        return []
    paths = []
    for node in next_stage_probability[start]:
        if node not in path:
            newpaths = find_all_paths(next_stage_probability, node, end, path)
            for newpath in newpaths:
                paths.append(newpath)
    return paths

terminals = [2,3,4,5]
next_stage_probability = {0: {1: Fraction(1, 2), 5: Fraction(1, 2)}, 1: {0: Fraction(4, 9), 3: Fraction(1, 3), 4: Fraction(2, 9)}}
d = {0: [1, 5], 1: [0, 3, 4], 2: [], 3: [], 4: [], 5: []}

paths_to_terminal = {}
for terminal in terminals:
    paths_to_terminal[terminal] = find_all_paths(next_stage_probability=next_stage_probability, start=0, end=terminal)

# this is important stage where next_stage_probability is your tree and you need to calculate probability to reach to states in terminals which are values 0 rows in matrix
terminal_probability = {}
for terminal_state in paths_to_terminal:
    if paths_to_terminal[terminal_state]:
        probability_for_this_terminal = 0
        considered_loop = []
        for path in paths_to_terminal[terminal_state]:
            this_path_probability = 1
            for x in range(len(path)-1):
                source, destination = path[x], path[x+1]
                current_to_next = next_stage_probability[source][destination]
                loop_list = [v for v,k in next_stage_probability.items() if source in k and v in next_stage_probability[source]]
                # loop_list = calculate_loop_states([source], next_stage_probability)
                this_path_probability = this_path_probability * current_to_next
                # print(path, (source, destination),loop_list, this_path_probability)
                if loop_list:
                    for loop_state in loop_list:
                        # print((source, loop_state))
                        if not considered_loop.__contains__((source, loop_state)) and not considered_loop.__contains__((loop_state, source)):
                            # print(Fraction(next_stage_probability[source][loop_state]), next_stage_probability[loop_state][source])
                            # print(type(next_stage_probability[source][loop_state]), type(next_stage_probability[loop_state][source]))
                            loop_val = next_stage_probability[source][loop_state] * next_stage_probability[loop_state][source]
                            this_path_probability = this_path_probability * loop_probability(loop_val)
                            considered_loop.append((source, loop_state))
                # print(this_path_probability)
            probability_for_this_terminal = probability_for_this_terminal + this_path_probability
            terminal_probability[terminal_state] = probability_for_this_terminal
    else:
        terminal_probability[terminal_state] = Fraction(0)
print(terminal_probability)
```

I hope it'll help you.

Comment: Some description wouldn't hurt.